# Sessions randomly clear on Win2008 ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, windows-server-2008, session-state

I couldn't find anything about this online so I thought I'd ask here. Do any of you have issues with sessions just randomly clearing on a Windows 2008 Server environment? This problem is completely random and very unpredictable. I have no code that clears sessions except on logout, and not quite sure what could be causing it (well, I have ideas...)

My host, who I've been with for many years (and never had a problem with) is telling me that Windows 2003 is better at managing session variables and that I will likely be rid of this session clearing issue if I were to move to a 2003 Server environment. Thing is, I'm already set up and running on IIS 7 with the URL Rewrite module and I'd rather not move or reconfigure URL rewriting. Tech support says the App Pool I am running on is configured properly. My session timeout is set to 60 minutes in Web.config and my host tells me that session timeout is set to 60 minutes for my domain.

I could optionally go with an Azure AppFabric Cache for sessions but I'd rather not pay an extra $50 a month--it's a pretty small and low income site. I'm currently using a SQL Azure database but from what I hear, database sessions are not ideal on SQL Azure.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using Shared AppPool and InProc Session state?

Comment: It feels very much like your app domain is recycling.  You can add a static DateTime to one of your classes, initialize it to DateTime.Now in a static constructor, access it in your main page to ensure the static constructor runs, and build a special page to display it's value.  Next time a session disappears, run your special page to see how long the app domain has been up for.

Comment: I have had similar issues. But i used few techniques to narrow down the causes. Try adding logging for Application_Start, Application_End, Application_Error, Session_Start, Session_End try to log as much information you can. This helped me to isolate one issue. My hoster has machine config with session timeout configuration of just 3 (YES) mins.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm sure this is an issue with my host, and I've just refactored to use some database calls. Storing in session was just a lot easier, but I think I have it fixed now. Ultimately when I need session again, I'll know to go with a better storage mechanism than InProc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely answer is your app pool is recycling on you for some reason or another which will dump your in process session every time. Proximate causes can be lots of things, especially if app pools are shared. An easy way to see if your app pool is getting dumped is to take advantage of asp.net heartbeat monitoring, it could be configured to email you when these events occur.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure what could be causing it, but I'm sure it's on the host's end. I ultimately just refactored to use a few business layer and database calls which should resolve the issue for now.

I'll definitely think about some more logging too. Couldn't hurt!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you modifying any files in the web site?

Changes to the folder or file structure of the web site often triggers an app pool recycling, resetting sessions. The work-around is to use a durable session store like the [SQL Server Session State provider](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I still haven't narrowed down what was causing it, but after sitting with it for most of last night I just decided to do away with Sessions (I was only storing about 8 of them) and just replaced them with BL and DB calls. I'll probably need to go back to sessions eventually, but for the time being this should work.

I'm using an Azure database and I've hard that the SQL Server Session State Provider isn't technically supported, but I could go with Azure AppFabric, which I'd likely do.

Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: It still isn't supported? I played around with Azure about a year ago and there was some hacky implementation out there that allowed SQL Session State Provider to work but it required the use of a worker role that did nothing but run a stored proc (in lieu of the jobs queue in SQL). It's crazy that they haven't added support yet.

Comment: Yeah, it's my understanding that Microsoft's preferred means of implementation is via AppFabric Cache which I can completely understand. I know the SQL Azure method is supposed to work fine and I could have easily gone that way too. I just decided to get rid of the 5-6 session variables I had and make a few extra database calls. Thanks for the comment though!  :)